# Regex to match timestamps and names

Tags: regex

I am working with this regex:

```
127.0.0.1 -Raphane [10/Oct/2008:14:55:38 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326127.0.0.1 -Varane [10/Dec/2007:13:12:02 -0700] "GET /apache_pbs.gif HTTP/1.0" 404 2336
```

I am trying to match the timestamps and names. I was able to get this working  for the name, but not the timestamp.

For name, I first matched the entire string and used 2 groups to find the 2 names in a single query with this regex:

```
^.*(\bRaphael\b)\s.*(\bVarane\b)\s.*
```

For the second part, request is to have one regex query to find both the timestamps.

Comment: Try [`\b(Raphael)\s+\[(.*?)\].*\b(Varane)\s+\[(.*?)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/PRk6qD/1)

Comment: Just FYI: in your input, you have `-Raphane`, but in the regex, you have `Raphael`.

Comment: Please provide expected output (Not sure if you want brackets `[]` and hyphens `-` on return)

Comment: What language/environment are you executing this regex in?

Answer (score 1):

1. This will match your timestamp: `(\[[^\]]+?\])`  Group 1 matches the timestamp.

[Test it here.](https://regex101.com/r/6NMxto/1)

2. If you'd like to match both the name and the timestamp using groups in the same match, this should work: `\-([A-Za-z]+?)[\s](\[[^\]]+?\])`  Group 1 matches the Name in the first match and Group 2 matches the timestamp.

[Test it here.](https://regex101.com/r/LHefdA/1)

Answer (score 0):

If from:

```
127.0.0.1 -Raphane [10/Oct/2008:14:55:38 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326127.0.0.1 -Varane [10/Dec/2007:13:12:02 -0700] "GET /apache_pbs.gif HTTP/1.0" 404 2336
```

you want to receive: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLT5BG/1))

```
Match 1
Full match  10-46   `-Raphane [10/Oct/2008:14:55:38 -0700`
Group 1.    11-18   `Raphane`
Group 2.    20-46   `10/Oct/2008:14:55:38 -0700`

Match 2
Full match  96-131  `-Varane [10/Dec/2007:13:12:02 -0700`
Group 1.    97-103  `Varane`
Group 2.    105-131 `10/Dec/2007:13:12:02 -0700`
```

then use: `~-([^\s]+)\s\[([^\]]+)~`

The `\s` will match whether your whitespace characters are spaces or tabs.
The `[^...]+` expressions are negated characters classes that will greedily (most efficiently) match one or more characters not listed inside the square brackets.  the leading `-` does not need to be escaped with a backslash.

If you specifically want to match these two names against a larger text with more names in it, then you can use: `~-(Raphane|Varane)\s\[([^\]]+)~` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gLT5BG/2)

Answer (score 0):

regex /-(\S+)\s[([^]]+)/

```
Match 1
Full match  10-46   `-Raphane [10/Oct/2008:14:55:38 -0700`
Group 1.    11-18   `Raphane`
Group 2.    20-46   `10/Oct/2008:14:55:38 -0700`
Match 2
Full match  96-131  `-Varane [10/Dec/2007:13:12:02 -0700`
Group 1.    97-103  `Varane`
Group 2.    105-131 `10/Dec/2007:13:12:02 -0700`
```

Here is demo.

https://regex101.com/r/xpnvth/1